Pycharm doesn't start Ubunut 20.4 LTS from instalation
[0.006s][warning][cds] Archived non-system classes are disabled because the java.system.class.loader property is specified (value = "com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader"). To use archived non-system classes, this property must not be set
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
2024-11-23 16:49:21,921 [     66]   WARN - #c.i.i.p.PluginManager - Problems found loading plugins:
  The Docker (id=Docker, path=~/.local/share/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2024.3/clouds-docker-impl, version=241.18034.82) plugin Plugin 'Docker' (version '241.18034.82') is not compatible with the current version of the IDE, because it requires build 241.* or older but the current build is PC-243.21565.199
2024-11-23 16:49:22,714 [    859]   WARN - #c.i.o.v.n.p.FSRecords - Records storage [/root/.cache/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2024.3/caches/records.dat] was in use by process [OwnershipInfo{owner pid: 879807, acquired at: 1732369564558}] which is not exist now (wasn't closed properly/crashed?) -> re-acquiring forcibly
2024-11-23 16:49:22,721 [    866]   WARN - #c.i.o.v.n.p.d.c.VFSContentStorageOverMMappedFile - Content map[/root/.cache/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2024.3/caches/content.dat.hashToId] is empty while content storage is not: re-building map from the storage
2024-11-23 16:49:22,760 [    905]   WARN - #c.i.o.v.n.p.PersistentFSLoader - [VFS load problem]: VFS wasn't safely shut down: records.wasClosedProperly is false
2024-11-23 16:49:22,816 [    961]   WARN - #c.i.o.v.n.p.PersistentFSLoader - [VFS load problem]: NOT_CLOSED_PROPERLY recovered, no problems remain
2024-11-23 16:49:24,573 [   2718]   WARN - #c.i.s.ComponentManagerImpl - `preload=NOT_HEADLESS` must be used only for core services (service=com.jetbrains.rdserver.toolWindow.BackendServerToolWindowManager, plugin=com.jetbrains.codeWithMe)
2024-11-23 16:49:24,574 [   2719]   WARN - #c.i.s.ComponentManagerImpl - `preload=TRUE` must be used only for core services (service=com.intellij.cwm.plugin.users.BackendUserManager, plugin=com.jetbrains.codeWithMe)
2024-11-23 16:49:24,574 [   2719]   WARN - #c.i.s.ComponentManagerImpl - `preload=TRUE` must be used only for core services (service=com.intellij.cwm.plugin.ports.CwmPortForwardingToolWindowManager, plugin=com.jetbrains.codeWithMe)
2024-11-23 16:49:24,574 [   2719]   WARN - #c.i.s.ComponentManagerImpl - `preload=TRUE` must be used only for core services (service=com.intellij.cwm.plugin.following.FollowMeManagerService, plugin=com.jetbrains.codeWithMe)
2024-11-23 16:49:25,155 [   3300]   WARN - #c.i.u.Alarm - Do not create alarm without coroutineScope: com.intellij.ui.GotItTooltip.<init>(GotItTooltip.kt:94)
2024-11-23 16:49:25,484 [   3629]   WARN - #c.i.i.s.p.i.SharedIndexInfrastructure - Skipped 1 shared indexes: bundled-python-sdk-8336bb23522e-31b6be0877a2-com.jetbrains.pycharm.community.sharedIndexes.bundled-PC-241.19072.16
2024-11-23 16:49:26,837 [   4982]   WARN - #c.i.o.a.Application - issue detected: ide.script.launcher.used
2024-11-23 16:49:27,015 [   5160]   WARN - #c.i.u.Alarm - Do not create alarm without coroutineScope: com.intellij.ui.GotItTooltip.<init>(GotItTooltip.kt:94)
2024-11-23 16:49:28,394 [   6539]   WARN - #c.i.u.Alarm - Do not create alarm without coroutineScope: com.intellij.ui.jcef.JBCefOsrComponent.<init>(JBCefOsrComponent.java:52)

I follow exactly this tutorial:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installation-guide.html
